# How to execute the below CURL command options -v -k -i -T in JAVA

Tags: java, curl

How to execute the below **CURL** command options **-v -k -i -T** in JAVA?

```
curl -v -k -i -T '/tmp/sample.txt' https://host:port/UUID
```

Comment: This is not duplicate.. this is something different, how to use command -v -k -i -T options to be used in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] args)`

[The exec method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) also has different overloads that allow you to specify the working directory etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Runtime.exec method in the normal way; see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29), or Google for a tutorial that you can understand.  (If you get this right, there is no need to process output, and you shouldn't need to worry about `exec(String)` misparsing the commmand line.)

However, you might run into problems with the `-v` option, because that is going to send  logging to stderr.  This doesn't get read by default, so there is a possibility that the command will lock up.

I recommend replacing `-v` with `-s`, which tells curl to be "silent".